# Codeigniter removing /index.php/class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've moved all of a local intranet site onto a new server with a new dns.  Everything seems to be working fine after changing setting and config files.
The only thing that is annoying me is that I can't get rid of the

`http://intranet/trunk/index.php/class`
on the old server

```
http://intrenet/trunk/class
```

worked fine, but now it throws up

> The requested URL /trunk/class/ was not found on this server.

But as I said, works fine when using the `/index.php/class`.  This should be fixable in the .htdocs (which I have put in the trunk folder, is that wrong?)

I've changed all the codeigniter configs too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that URL-Rewriting (mod_rewrite) is enabled  in your web server.
Then create a .htaccess file in your htdocs directory with the below code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and also edit config.php and remove the index.php  [image]

Comment: I've done the .htaccess and the index file removal, will check that mod-rewrite is enabled and get back to you!

Comment: OK, all 3 now appear to be ok, but still no re-direct.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i resolved with this .htaccess file

```
# Mod Rewrite active
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Set base path
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /Workspace/codeigniter/

    # Denied access to system directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    # Denied access to application directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    # Check for error request
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# Mod Rewrite inactive
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Remember to set

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

in the config/config.php file and to change the path of the "RewriteBase" var.